# How to Place TextView and EditText on same line without using xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

- I used xml and very much familiar with xml only for layouts.
- I am trying to code in activity and want to develop view like,

> textview editetxt
>
> textview edittext
>
> textview edittext button

```
LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

TextView textViewName = new TextView (MainActivity.this); 
textViewName .setText("Name:");

Edittext editTextName= new Edittext (MainActivity.this);

lLayout.addView(textViewName );
lLayout.addView(editTextName);
```

- It will obviously come vertical, but how to place horizontal...
- I searched but not got any solution. I tried but, I don't know how to place vertical layout first and inside of it horizontal...
  -please help me to sort out this issue if any one knows...

Comment: lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.Horizontal);

Comment: that I know.. but after that it will be horizontal only... first base layout should be vertical and for three rows should be horizontal.. that's what i need

Comment: then you need to another Layout for that in single layout u canot make both horznt and vertcal

Comment: please give reply or solution if any one knows... rather to down the question...

Comment: @sania: will you please suggest me

Comment: so, I need to give two layouts in xml and then what to do in activity class?

Comment: no u can do manually to..but why u  are not creating in xml.y manually creating??

Comment: because data coming from web service is not fixed.. some times two rows to be created sometimes 3 may 4 also.... thats why i need to generate those views dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

you can create another LinearLayout hLayout inside the lLayout(vertical) and set the orientation of this new layout to be horizontal using

```
hLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.Horizontal);
```

Add it to llayout

```
lLayout.addView(hlayout);
```

Now place both your textview nad edittext inside the hlayout.

Comment: how but... for that I need 15 reputation... yes I am trying.. it it worked I will let you know...

Answer (score 0):

```
package manish.example.testproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int m = 3; // here write number of view want show

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
        main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
            LinearLayout li = new LinearLayout(this);
            li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView t = new TextView(this);
            t.setText("Name : ");
            EditText e = new EditText(this);
            li.addView(t);
            li.addView(e);
            main.addView(li);
        }
        setContentView(main);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly, but as per my understanding, I am writing my code

```
LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
LinearLayout Layout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
TextView textViewName = new TextView (MainActivity.this); 
textViewName .setText("Name:");
EditText editTextName= new EditText (MainActivity.this);
lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lLayout.addView(Layout2);
Layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
Layout2.addView(textViewName );
Layout2.addView(editTextName);
```